# Python listing directories in Windows XP from Linux host

Tags: python

I'm currently running python on Linux machine and have a windows XP guest running on vbox.
I want to access the shared folder on the xp machine. i tried the following command but always get the same error.

```
d = os.listdir(r"\\remoteip\share")   
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the shared folder on xp was created by creating a new folder in the Shared Documents folder and I'm able to ping machines.

Comment: You can't use paths like `\\windowsmachine\share` on Linux, but you can either mount the file system and get something like `/mount/windowsmachine/share`, or `smb://windowsmachine/share` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows sharing is implemented using smb protocol. Windows Explorer and most of the Linux file managers (like Nautilus) make it transparent to the user, so it is easy to do common file operations on files\folders shared through smb.

However, Linux (and thus Python that runs on top of it) does not add this abstraction by default on file system level (though you can mount smb share as part of your fs).

So, in the end, to access those files you can:

1. mount your share using `mount -t cifs` (man or google for details) and then access your share from Python as usual folder (to my mind this is rather kludgy solution)
2. use library that deals specifically with smb, like [pysmb](http://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/) (here is the [relevant docs section](http://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html)) and do your file operations with it's help.

Hope this will help.

Comment: and what if I want to access the shared folder in Linux fs from the windows machine ??

Comment: @Gr33n if you are going to share Linux folder through smb (samba) and access it from Windows machine then in (1) you actually do not have to mount anything (since smb support is added on fs level), just access your files, and if you choose (2) then you'll have to do pretty much the same (i.e. use pysmb to access those files).

Comment: i guess `os.listdir(r"\\remoteip\share")` works on windows system only. If its so then what is the command for this when both the systems are linux

Comment: @Gr33n as I've said, if you run Python on Linux and want to use fs means to access share (it does not really matter what hosts this share - Windows or Linux) - you have to `mount` smb share to fs.

Comment: Got it. Just a last question, its clear to me that it does not works on different file systems (windows and linux), but why is it so that it doesn't works on both linux fs and works on windows fs.

Comment: @Gr33n Well, I cannot tell you about this for sure, but I think most of the reasons are either historical or policy ones. At some point in time MS guys decided that their next killer feature will be "sharing", so they invested in smb and integrated it deeply into Windows. Windows always lived in it's own world, so architecture guys could afford choosing one specific protocol and integrating it deeply into OS.

Comment: ... Unix\Linux philosophy and thus architecture is more open-minded and flexible. This comes with cost of keeping specific things (like third party protocols pushed by MS) out of "core" functionality, but still allowing to plug-in that functionality. What you do by using `mount` is just "plugging in" the smb plug.